# Haskell Type Error

Tags: haskell, types

Consider the following piece of Haskell code:

```
 type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]

 item :: Parser Char
 item = \ inp -> case inp of
                 [] -> []
                 (x:xs) -> [(x, xs)]

 ret :: a -> Parser a
 ret v = \ inp -> [(v, inp)]

 parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
 parse p inp = p inp

 pseq :: Parser (Char, Char)
 pseq = do x <- item
           item
           y <- item
           ret (x, y)

 ac = parse pseq "abcdef"
```

When trying to run the above code in hugs (Version September 2006), I get the following error message:

```
Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : pseq
*** Type           : [Char] -> [(([(Char,[Char])],[(Char,[Char])]),[Char])]
*** Does not match : Parser (Char,Char)
```

And, when I remove my type declaration for "pseq", I get the following error message:

```
Unresolved top-level overloading
*** Binding             : pseq
*** Outstanding context : Monad ((->) [Char])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making Parser a Monad is easy, and I think resorting to ListT or StateT is probably overkill here.

```
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a, String)])
    -- make this a distinct type
    -- now the function is "wrapped", though at no run-time cost

instance Monad Parser where
    return = ret    -- you already had it defined
    (>>=) = bind    -- added below
    -- this instance makes Parser a Moand, and lets it work with do notation

item :: Parser Char
item = Parser $ \ inp -> case inp of
                         [] -> []
                         (x:xs) -> [(x, xs)]
    -- need to "wrap" up the function as a Parser value

ret :: a -> Parser a
ret v = Parser $ \ inp -> [(v, inp)]
    -- need to "wrap" up the function as a Parser value

bind :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
bind p f = Parser $ \ s -> case parse p s of
                           [] -> []
                           [(a, s')] -> parse (f a) s'
    -- the only function you were missing
    -- it is worth making sure you understand how it works

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse (Parser p) inp = p inp
    -- needs to "unwrap" the newtype here

pseq :: Parser (Char, Char)
pseq = do x <- item
          item
          y <- item
          ret (x, y)

ac = parse pseq "abcdef"
    -- you probably meant pseq here, not seq
```

Lastly, you use the return type of `[(a, String)]`, so that you can indicate things which can't parse. But the list only ever has zero or one items in it. You should look into the types `Maybe` and `Either` which would likely be clearer in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're trying to use `do`-notation for `Parser`, but it's not exactly a `Monad`. It is sort of, because there's a `Monad` instance for `r ->`, but that makes the type on the right-hand side of the `->` the "element" type of the `Monad`, and here you want the element type to be the `a` in `[(a,String)]`. You need to make the definition of `Parser` a `newtype`, and write a custom `Monad` instance for it (or compose it out of exising monads/transformers like `ListT` and `StateT`).